# How do I implement two iterable columns in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, tweepy

I'm brand new to programming, but got sucked into a school project that feels pretty far over my head. I'm scraping Twitter data related to BTC, and trying to find the average sentiment score per month. I got access to Twitter API, and all that, but I'm having troubles creating my dataframe. I can create one column that houses either "tweet.text" or "tweet.created_at", but can't seem to make two columns with each.

Here's what I have so far:

```
search_words = "bitcoin"
date_since = "2022-2-1"

tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
                   q = search_words,
                   since = date_since,
                   lang = "en",
                   count = 1000).items(1000)

a = {'Tweets':[tweet.text for tweet in tweets], 'Date':[tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient='index')
df = df.transpose()
df
```

The result:

[image]

How can I generate the desired output?

Comment: Your code seems just fine. I guess [`created_at`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v4.8.0/v2_models.html#tweepy.Tweet.created_at) for each Tweet is None.

Comment: You may be over complicating things though, I would bet the api returns a JSON response. Check out [pd.read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html#pandas-read-json) and [pd.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html#pandas-json-normalize)

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `a['Date']` as an intermediate step? When I was just starting out, I was told this good rule to keep in mind while debugging: At each step in your code, think about the inputs, decide what you expect the output to be, and verify that output before moving to the next step

Comment: I've swapped the first column, "tweets.text", with "tweet.created_at" and it successfully posts all the date/ times. When I try to return the second column though, it just prints a blank array :/